# Let $G$ be an arbitrary group.Let $S$ and $H$ be subgroups of $G$ which are not equal with $G$. Show that $G\setminus H$ is not subset of $S$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be an arbitrary group.
Let $S$ and $H$ be subgroups of $G$ which are not equal with $G$. Show that $G\setminus H$ is not subset of $S$.

$S$ subgroup of $G$, then for all $s_1, s_2 \in S, s_1s_2^{-1} \in S$ and $H$ subgroup of $G$, then for all $h_1,h_2 \in H, h_1h_2^{-1} \in H$. Let $G = \{e_G,g,g^2,\dots, g^{n-1}\}$.
What next?

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Why are you assuming $G$ is cyclic?

Comment: $G-H$ is set of all elements in $G$ which are not in $H$. And then what?

Comment: Is my assumption above not true? So, how?

Comment: Whoops, misread question.

Comment: But, from the problem, $S \ne G$.

Comment: This reads like a "no effort" question. Why is $G$ assumed to be cyclic, and why are you telling us that $s_1s_2^{-1}\in S$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you need to prove that $G\ne S\cup H$. Suppose that $G=S\cup H$ and $S\ne G\ne H$. If $H\subseteq S$ or $S\subseteq H$, then $G=H\cup S$ is either $S$ or $H$, a contradiction.

Hence  $S\not\subseteq H$ and $H\not\subseteq S$. Let $s\in S\setminus H$ and $h\in H\setminus S$. Since $sh\in G$ it is either in $S$ or in $H$. In the first case $h=s^{-1}(sh)\in S$, a contradiction. In the second case $s=(sh)h^{-1}\in H$, a contradiction.

Hence $S\cup H\ne G$.

Comment: The problem is equivalent to show that $G \ne S \cup H$ ?

Comment: Yes, $G\setminus H\not\subseteq S$ is equivalent to $G\ne S\cup H$.

Comment: How to conclude that $sh \in G$ ?

Comment: Both $s$ and $h$ are in $G$ and $G$  is a group.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. :D

Comment: $s \in S \backslash H$ then $s \in G$ ? How?

Comment: I still confusing for that equivalence. Can you show that that is equivalent?

Comment: $s\in S\setminus H$ then $s\in S$, Since $S\subset G$, $s\in G$

Comment: But, $S \ne G$ ?

Comment: The equivalence is true for arbitrary sets $S,H, G$. Draw the Venn diagram.

Comment: $S\subset G$, $s\in S$. Then $s\in G$ by the definition of $\subset$.

Comment: If $H \subseteq S$ or $S \subseteq H$, then $G = H U S$ is either...

Comment: what is the meaning of either .... ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  It is well-known that the union of two subgroups is again a subgroup if and only if the subgroups are nested, that is $S\le H $ (wlog).

Combine this with the fact that if $G-H\subset S$, then $G=H\cup S$.

Finally if $S$ and $H$ are nested and neither is all of $G$, we are done.

Answer (score 1):

See also the answer of @JCCA: a group cannot be written as the union of two of its *proper* (:= being not equal to the whole group) subgroups. Hence it follows:

**Proposition** Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of a group $G$. Then $\langle G \setminus H \rangle=G$.

**Proof** Obviously $G=H \cup G \setminus H \subseteq H \cup \langle G \setminus H \rangle$. Since $H$ is proper the proposition follows.

So in your case, if $G \setminus H \subseteq S$. then, since $S$ is a subgroup, also $\langle G \setminus H \rangle \subseteq S$, a contradiction to $S$ being proper.